# Unable to open Unity after update

Tags: unity, chromebook

I am completely new to the Ubuntu world and just hit my first major problem while installing unity on my chromebook C720. I installed it without problem using crouton and just updated it using the instructions here: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Upgrade-chroot-release
But when I tried to update crouton with the following line:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u
```

I get the following error message:

```
/home/colingb/Downloads/crouton: 62: /home/colingb/Downloads/crouton: curl: not found
Failed to download crouton installer.
```

I redownloaded crouton and checked my internet and proxy settings but it still doesn't work...

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you paste the line no. 62 of the script?

Comment: curl -# -L --connect-timeout 60 --max-time 300 --retry 2 \

Comment: I think you don't have 'curl' installed.Install it by "sudo apt-get install curl".....and then proceed again.

Comment: Ok I was able install 'curl' but when I try to update precise again, I get the following message:
/mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots not found.
    
/usr/local/chroots/precise does not exist; cannot update.

Valid chroots:
What does that mean?! (Sorry for the syntax, I am unable to organize my code...)

Comment: I am still unable to open Ubuntu... Anybody can help??

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into the same problem. The issue (at least for me) was that I was trying to update from within a chroot.

You have to run `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n chrootname` from the ChromeOS shell: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, type `shell` and hit enter, and **then** enter the update command.